# dynamic sql embedded in select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a table `Users`,

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ Id ║ Name  ║  Db  ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Peter ║ DB1  ║
║  2 ║ John  ║ DB16 ║
║  3 ║ Alex  ║ DB23 ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

and many databases that have the same structure (Same tables, same procedures, ...), so every database have a table named `Project`, and this is the structure of `Project` table,

```
╔════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║ Id ║ Request ║ Information ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║     126 ║ XB1         ║
║  2 ║     126 ║ D6          ║
║  3 ║     202 ║ BM-23       ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

So, when I query a database :

```
SELECT count(distinct([Request])) as nbrRequests
  FROM [SRV02].[DB1].[dbo].[Project]
```

I get this result :

```
╔═════════════╗
║ NbrRequests ║
╠═════════════╣
║           2 ║
╚═════════════╝
```

Now, what I want is to "link"/"join" ... results from the table `Users` to this query, where the column `Db` in `Users` table is the name of my database, so I can get a result like this :

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════╦═════════════╗
║ Id ║ Name  ║  Db  ║ NbrRequests ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ Peter ║ DB1  ║           2 ║
║  2 ║ John  ║ DB16 ║           3 ║
║  3 ║ Alex  ║ DB23 ║           6 ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════╩═════════════╝
```

I'm trying with dynamic SQL, but no luck.

**NB :** Every user has only one database, and a database belong to only one user, it's one-to-one relationship

Comment: Is there any link between the requests table and the user table other than it is on a specific database? And if not, is there more than one user per database, and if yes what would be the results?

Comment: please specify table relations and how you  are expecting nbrrequests as 2,3,6

Comment: Db is the only link, and every user has only one database, and a database belong to only one user.

Comment: Why "no luck" with dynamic sql?   What was the query you tried, and what error did you get?

Comment: @TabAlleman, No luck because I couldn't find how to join Users table to DBxx.Project table, I found a solution, you can see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35797984/1460399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining these 2 answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795690/1460399 and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795189/1460399, I got this solution :

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'SELECT u.Id, u.Name, u.Db, dbCts.nbrRequests  FROM [Users] u INNER JOIN (';

DECLARE @QueryLength INT= LEN(@Query);

SELECT @Query = @Query
                +CASE WHEN LEN(@Query) > @QueryLength THEN ' UNION ' ELSE '' END
               +'SELECT '''+Db+''' as db, count(distinct(Request)) as nbrRequests FROM [SRV02].'+Db+'[Project]'
FROM Users;

SET @Query = @Query+') dbCts ON u.Db = dbCts.db';

EXECUTE (@Query);
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you can do it is with a UNION counting every specific database table and giving it a identification for the database, like this:

```
SELECT u.Id, u.Name, u.Db, dbCts.nbrRequests
  FROM [Users] u INNER JOIN
      (SELECT 'DB1' as db, count(distinct([Request])) as nbrRequests
         FROM [SRV02].[DB1].[dbo].[Project]
       UNION 
       SELECT 'DB16', count(distinct([Request])) as nbrRequests
         FROM [SRV02].[DB16].[dbo].[Project]
       UNION  
       SELECT 'DB23', count(distinct([Request])) as nbrRequests
         FROM [SRV02].[DB23].[dbo].[Project]
      ) dbCts ON u.Db = dbCts.db
```

Don't forget to add the server and schema to the `Users` table I didn't because there is no such info on your question.

Also in order to do this, your connected user must have privileges on all databases.

Comment: I dont think that this request is dynamic, I have to change it every time I add a user

Comment: @Hamza_L It is not Dynamic. And you have to change it every time you add a Database, given that this isn't a simple task, adding two lines in query wouldn't be that much. But it is only one approach. Feel free to chose the best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL can be very tricky.

This example builds the select query from the users table.  The variable @Query is incremented for each line returned by the Users table.  Each row returns a query that joins the local users table to the projects table in a remote db.  The results of each query are [UNIONED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) together.

**Example**

```
-- Wil holds our dynamic query.
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- Builds our dynamic statement.
SELECT
    @Query = 
        @Query 
        + CASE WHEN LEN(@Query) > 0 THEN ' UNION ALL ' ELSE '' END
        + 'SELECT u.Id, u.Name, u.Db, COUNT(DISTINCT p.Request) AS NbrRequest '
        + 'FROM [SVR02].' + QUOTENAME(DB) + 'dbo.Project AS p INNER JOIN Users u ON u.Db= p.Db '
        + 'GROUP BY u.Id, u.Name, u.Db'
FROM
    Users
;

-- Executes the dynamic statement.
EXECUTE (@Query);
```

This example uses [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to help avoid [SQL injection attacks.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: why is there u.Id = p.Id ? u.Id is the id of the user, and p.id is the id of the project